Big O calculation for preconditioner matrix M
I'm working on a problem where I need to compute the matrices $M^{-1}$  and I'm trying to determine the number of floating point operations (FLOPs) required for it.
I am working with a sequence of matrix operations involving the matrices $S$, $R$, $H_{\text{norm}}$, and $A$, defined as follows:
$S = \text{diag}(S_{11}, \ldots, S_{mm})$, where each $S_{jj}$ is randomly either $-1$ or $+1$.
$p$ is a small positive integer.
$R$ is an $(n+p) \times m$ row selection matrix, with exactly one non-zero entry per row, which is randomly placed and distinct across all rows.
$\Phi = R H_{\text{norm}} S$ where $H_{\text{norm}}$ is the normalized Hadamard matrix of order $m$, making $\Phi$ an $(n+p) \times m$ matrix.
$A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix.
We want to compute $ M^{-1}=A^T \Phi^T \Phi A$. Given that the matrix-vector product $H_m v$ can be computed in $m \log m$ time for any vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^m$, how can I leverage this efficiency to compute $ M^{-1}$
From my analysis a column of $A$, $a_i$ with the $\Phi$ matrix has cost $ O(m \log(m)+m+n+p)$ as $ O(m)$ for the $S$ matrix and $n+p$ for the $R$ matrix and since we have $n$ columns that would be $O(n(m \log(m)+m+n+p))$ and for the final calculation of $(A^T \Phi^T)( \Phi A)$ it would be $O(n^2(n+p))$ Though I am not sure that this is the most efficient way. I was told the analysis should not involve $p$.
